# Best way to allocate large local memory in a C++ function

Tags: c++, memory-management, allocation

I have a program where I'm a table of a decently large block of memory, it's a structure with two integers (they would have to be at least 4 bytes a piece to hold up to 1,000,000,000).  The structure currently has a little more than 500 entries into it.  So we're talking about 4k.  4k of stack space doesn't seem like a lot, but it does seem wasteful for a function that may only be called once in a blue moon.  (Assume we'll call it once over the life time of a program, so if it's slightly slow to allocate, it's ok as that space is more value over the allocation time).

The code is just a simple look up of values, the code to generate it is quite heavy, and we only are looking for specific values anyways.  I've the code already, and the look up is by far faster, so there's no question that I want to go down this route.  I could add in a file load to get the data out of a file, but to me that seems overkill at least at this point.

Now there's two ways I can think of allocating it.  Making it a global variable, and making it a local variable.  Obviously, local is the way to go as it's only this function that needs the table.  However what I'm looking for is if there's any keywords I can use, or any way of loading that variable (currently it's just a array of these pairs) that will be the most beneficial.

My best case is to make it attempt to be in memory only for the scope of the function, and then to allow that memory to be returned to the system. in as efficient a way as possible.   Is there a step beyond making the data local that I should take?

Comment: Do you know at compile-time how many entries this table will have, or is it generated at runtime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a step beyond making the data local that I should take?

Nothing more. It should look like this:

```
void proc() {
  t_thing things[500]; // << you could use std::array here too
}
```

It's doubtful that it is 'slow' for your needs. If you want to improve this, specifying the alignment could help.

Answer (score 2):

Just allocate it on the stack

```
void dowork()
{
     int temp[512];
}
```

That is not wasteful, as it will only be allocated on the stack during the execution of the function.

Alternatively (if stack space isn't plentiful),

```
void dowork()
{
     std::vector<int> temp(512);
}
```

which will put the bulk of allocated memory on the heap

Comment: What would using `std::vector` or `std::array` bring here? As I understand, the array is of constant size and known only to this function.

Comment: @PaulManta: it would avoid the risk of stack overflows. It's generally a bad idea to put large amounts of data on the stack. I wouldn't normally worry about it when it's only 4kb, but it's a valid consideration nevertheless

Comment: @sehe I don't think he should put the data on the stack, but using these containers might be overkill. The array is local to the function, so there isn't really any risk of not knowing its size and overflowing.

Comment: @Paul Manta: `vector` and `array` are standard containers (with all the nice things about them (e.g. algorithms become way easier if you can say "x.begin(), x.end()" and "x.size()"), plain old arrays are not.

Comment: @PaulManta: Oh and, containers are never overkill, plain old arrays are (in the general case).

Comment: @phresnel So? If those containers offer something that it hard to achieve with plain arrays, of course he should use them. But in a local context, there's really no reason I shouldn't just use `size_t size = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]);` and `array` and `array + size` instead of those functions you showed.

Comment: This is a different kind of overflow. If you try to allocate 5MB on the stack, but the stack is only 3MB, (see `rlimit`), your program just dies.

Comment: @PaulManta: The more complex the operations, the higher the probability of bugs. Performancewise, `std::vector` and `std::array` come for free, provided the compiler has enough insight. And they lessen the probability of bugs because you don't have to be redundant and can type less.

Comment: @Dave: Not in the case of std::vector. Also 3MB stacks are (very) rare. My point is: do the simplest thing, don't optimize prematurely but if you must, use the standard library to do the work.

Comment: @sehe, agreed, My point was that a giant array could overflow the stack, contrary to PaulMantra's comment

Answer (score 1):

If it is constant between function calls and you could spare 4K of memory that you might not need that often, you could make it a local static variable.

```
void func()
{
    static int array[] = {...};
}
```

It will act almost exactly as a global variable, except it will only be visible from inside this function.

The memory it needs will be allocated in the data segment (same place where globals are allocated) when you load your program and freed when the application closes. Depending on how you generate this table, the values might also be set when you load the program, but only if they are constant. If the values are not known at compile time, they will be set upon the first call of this function.

Comment: Its not created on the first call, its created when the binary is loaded (or more precisely - created at the compilation time, and allocated in memory when the binary is loaded).

Comment: @littleadv Corrected. About what you wrote in the parentheses, it really depends on how it is generated.

Comment: @Dave What do you mean by 'created'? If you mean 'allocated', I agree. If you mean 'initialized', I say it depends.

Comment: Doesn't this avoid any benefits of making it Local?   I'm trying to avoid memory being used when the function isn't called (because while 4k isn't a lot, it's still a large amount of memory for a function that is rarely used)

Comment: This is _more_ wasteful and not threadsafe. Heck, it is not even re-entrant

Comment: @Kinglink If memory is what you want to save, this isn't the right way to go. This solution will only save you having to initialize the array on every call (which is desirable only if initializing it is expensive).